# Iframe - from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Here is how i call the content from the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="InnerIframe" class="FrameCSS" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Here is the CSS of the iframe:

```
.FrameCSS
{
   position:absolute;
   top:-350px;
   left:-20px;
   width:400px;
   height:700px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

As you can see i use `top:-350px` to point from where i want the iframe to start showing content from page: http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/

I want to ask is there any way with jQuery or some other method that i can start the iframe showing content from `<div id="StartIframe"></div>` and and the iframe grabbing content at `<div id="EndIframe"></div>` ?

Basicly, am i able to make the an iframe get content from a page starting from specific div and ending with a specific div ?

Comment: i'm afraid you can't filter what is shown on an iframe.

Comment: You would have to grab the content via PHP Curl for example, than to change it, including adding `<base href="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg" />`.

Comment: Try `<iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/#StartIframe" ...>`.

Comment: Can you control the HTML output at beta.sportsdirect.bg? If you can, than you can output different HTML for some GET parameter, for example: `http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/?iframed=1`